# задача на количество пилообразных последовательностей

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

Не получается решить задачу(.

ссылка на задачу : https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=3001#1

Пилообразные последовательности

Назовем последовательность пилообразной, если каждый ее элемент либо строго больше, либо строго меньше своих соседей. По данными числам n и k определите число пилообразных последовательностей длины n, составленных из чисел 1..k.

Входные данные
Программа получает на вход два натуральных числа n и k, не превосходящих 10^6. Гарантируется, что ответ не превосходит 2^31-1.

Выходные данные
Выведите ответ на задачу.

Примеры
входные данные

```
3 3
```

выходные данные

```
10
```

Comment: Как может быть 10 пилообразных, если их всего - 6?

Comment: @Igor Может, они могут повторяться?...

Comment: @Igor, `[1,2,1], [2,1,2],[3,1,3],[3,2,3],[2,3,2],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[2,3,1],[2,1,3],[3,1,2]` - 10 пилообразных по 3 числа, составленных из чисел 1...3.

Comment: @Leonid А-а-а, *числа* могут повторяться. Понял.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ваши попытки решения. Что вы сделали? Что не получилось? Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Представим, что для некой длины `M` мы имеем:

- массив `UP` длиной `k+1`, ячейка `UP[k]` которого содержит количество пилообразных последовательностей длиной `M`, **заканчивающихся** числом `k`, а **перед этим было меньшее** число (отсюда название. Понятно, что `UP[1] = 0`)
- а также массив `DOWN` той же длины, ячейка `DOWN[k]` которого содержат количество пилообразных последовательностей длиной `M`, **заканчивающихся** числом `k`, а перед этим было **большее** число (ясно, что `DOWN[k] = 0`)

Например, для `M=3, k=3` `UP[2] = 2`  - это `[2,1,2] и  [3,1,2]`, но сами последовательности мы не генерируем

Заполняем массивы шаг за шагом (понадобится четыре  массива - для текущего и для следующего шага). Значение в ячейке нового массива `UP` - это сумма некой части старого массива `DOWN` и наоборот.
В конце, после `N`-го шага, суммируем все ячейки обоих массивов.

Для `100,100` считается доли секунды, ответ
`3773018431531573052522230433297637206758217297263096271159156235247115149777810286853214926143448593916049821132944802103999840915098829452130589430766903146390723369894978956835816`, так что для ограничения результата 32-битным числом проблем со временем не будет.

Стоит посмотреть, не подчиняются ли значения какой-то закономерности. Вдруг формула простая получится...

Comment: Мне кажется, что такая идея не пройдёт по времени. Возможно я ошибаюсь

Comment: Значит теста 10^6 и 10^6 не будет? Я думал, что будет.

Comment: @Битный овощ Может быть n=10^6, k=2. Уже для k=3 число огромное.